# Python multithreaded memoization

Tags: python, memoization

Python multithreaded memoization, is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes it's possible, could involve Locks and Queues, searching for cache will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible. In fact, I think that the straightforward single-threaded implementation should work just fine, assuming that it is acceptable that some redundant calculations may be performed in the case when the same function is called with the same parameters in parallel.

For an illustration of the scenario, your memoization procedure will probably look something like this:

```
if args not in cache:
    cache[args] = func(args)
return cache[args]
```

If two threads hit this spot at the same time with the same `args`, they may both invoke `func(args)` in parallel, while it would be more efficient to invoke just one instance of the calculation and for the other one to wait until the first one completes. This may not be too much of a problem for you. If it is, a solution using locks (from the `threading` module) to block threads with matching arguments should be quite straightforward.

Comment: @gnibbler: I haven't tried anything. I got into a discussion with a friend who was using memoization to speed up some big AI calculations but found some of his input to still take a long time to calculate on his computer. Since it's a multicore computer I suggested he try multithreading his application and he wasn't sure that he would be able to do it without messing up his memoization. So out of curiosity I decided to ask the experts here if it was indeed possible. Seems it is...the folks at this community never cease to amaze me with their solutions. :)